# ¿Cómo dar soporte a FTP en varios sitios web en la misma máquina con ProFTPD?

Tags: linux, ftp, virtualhost

Expongo una serie de dudas de proftpd para dar soporte a ftp en varios sitios web en la misma maquina.

En este caso dispongo de una vps con una solo IP publica, y tengo registrado varios dominios que apuntan a la misma vps.

la estrucura de directorios es la siguiente:

- /var/wwww/sitio1.com   -> 1er sitio web
- /var/wwww/sitio2.com   -> 2do sitio web
- ...

y asi sucesivamente, todo con los permisos de usuario:grupo  `www-data:www-data`  y `755` de permisos,

En apache tengo cada dominio con un virtual host  basado en nombre de dominio y no me da ningun problema.

Pero la parte de FTP,  que lo tengo  con proftpd  tengo dudas de como enfocarlo.

Me gustaria surtir el servicio  para que  si el cliente se conecta con la direccion de dominio del sitio1.com con un usuario concreto  permita su acceso y subida de ficheo  a dicho sitio.

Los usuarios de proftpd esta  encerrados en su home como usuarios virtuales el cual todo lo que suben lo suben con usuario y grupo www-data:www-data hasta ahi todo perfecto. (esto lo hice con usuarios virtuales por fue la unica manera de que lo que subiesen se quedase con los permisos de www-data:www-data).

Lo que quiero es que si instroducen el dominio1  con usuario1 me redirija a su home , de lo acontrario me de un error de autentificacion.

Lo que tengo ahora es que si introduce el domino1 con el usuario2  me redirecciona al home del usuario2  cosa que no quiero dado que el usuario2 no es propietario del dominio1.

He mirado el tema de virualhost en proftpd pero parece que no trabaja de la misma manera que en apache.

Answer (score 1):

Esto se soluciona configurando diferentes virtualhost para cada dominio (que es lo que creo que has hecho), pero a la hora de conectarse en vez de ir a su home que cada dominio apunte a *x* ruta.

Por ejemplo:

Si se accede vía **usuario1.dominio.com** se manda el usuario a **/var/ftp/usuario1** . Los permisos de esta carpeta serían; [dueño: usuario1] y [grupo: www-data]

Para asignar los permisos:

```
chown usuario1:www-data /var/ftp/usuario1
chmod -R 750 /var/ftp/usuario1
```

Con esto consigues que cuando usuario2 acceda a usuario1.dominio.com le mande error de 'insuficcient permision' (ya que solo usuario1 & www-data tienen permisos para acceder a /var/ftp/usuario1).

Comment: ¿Podrías resumir brevemente una configuración de varios virtualhost en el mismo servidor? Es decir, cómo lo pondrías en el fichero de Apache.